# Issues with defining dates in Google App Script ~new Date()~

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I've been having some issues with converting strings into dates with Google App Script for Google Sheets, but now I actually know the first issue to tackle:

No matter what I do, I'm unable to call the class Date() (within Google App Script for Google Sheets).

It apparently does not recognize it as a callable class, and so I cannot define dates within any codes.

Has anybody faced a similar issue? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: Try this: `var dt=new Date(); Logger.log(dt);`  Let me know what you get when you view logs.

Comment: Note the use of `new` in Cooper's comment. If that doesn't resolve your issue, then please post your code. Please, always post your code when asking a question.

Comment: For some reason the `Date()` class started working, so I definitely have to keep studying on js. In any case, thank you @Cooper and @Diego for the suport. Also,  @Diego, I didn't include any code because it was an issue with the editor itself, not any particular code that I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find some good documentation on how to use date functions on apps script, basically, it uses JavaScript build-in date functions:

**Specific documentation of Apps Script Date function:**

Google developers: [Working with Dates and Times on Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)

**Documentation on JavaScript Date function:**

MDN Web Standard docs: [JavaScript build-in Date function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)